# ParentContainsErrorRecordException while running mvn install -Psetup, seed, test-data comand

Tags: ajax, maven, mvn-repo

```
PS D:\Upgrad\01_Code from upgrad\04_BACKEND_INTEGRATION\proman-backend\proman-db>  mvn install -Psetup,seed,test-data
At line:1 char:21
+  mvn install -Psetup,seed,test-data
+                     ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

How can i resolve this error?

i wan to achieve BUILD SUCCESS